# Any free libraries to send/receive SMS, send/receive Calls using GSM Modem?

Tags: windows, sms, modem, gsm, telecommunication

I want to make a windows application in which I want to send ,receive and process SMS using GSM Modem( [this one](http://cgi.ebay.in/3G-USB-Modem-Huawei-E1550-High-Speed-3-6Mbps-CHEAPEST-/260675094112?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item3cb1724660#ht_1873wt_1141) ), It would be very helpful If you provide me link to any opensource library or application which do the same. I am good in MFC and Qt, so any C++ or C library or app reference would be much better.

It would be great help, If you can tell me/Give some reference of how to do incoming call processing. I want to read user's keyboard input during call ( Like press 1 for Apple and press 2 for Microsoft ). As in next version I want to support this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the SMS part you can use the open source [Kannel](http://kannel.org/overview.shtml) server. It will work with GSM modems and provide an interface (HTTP) for your application to interact with it.

Call wise, you are probably looking for an [IVR](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/IVR) solution. You can write the branching logic (voice menu, press 1 etc) in its language. [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/applications/ivr) seems to support that but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Java library SMSlib can do it for SMS and USSD. Unfortunately, MMS isn't supported.